# Meteor setTimeout from collection before hook

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor server code needs to send email only if the `category` property has not been populated in myCollection after 2 minutes.

But it is sending the email every time regardless.  Any suggestions so that it only send email if the `category` is still blank after 2 minutes? thx

```
let myFunc = function (){
  myCollection.inert({lastName: 'john'});
  //run other code to populate the myCollection.category
}

myCollection.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  if (userId === '8mmjdueej') {
     lib.alertAdmin(doc);
   }
});

   'alertAdmin': function (Obj) {
      Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
          let category = myCollection.find({lastName: Obj.name}).bigCategory;
          if (!category) {
            lib.sendEmail(null, 'failed to get category for: ' + Obj.name);
          }
        },
        120000);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let category = myCollection.find({lastName: Obj.name}).bigCategory;
```

here could be the problem. A `find` returns the Mongo's cursor, not the document itself. You can use `findOne` for this.